# The level (or "levels"?) of residual host cell protein in all drug samples

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> The **level** of residual host cell protein in all drug **samples** complies with the regulatory requirements.

Is it okay to use the singular "level" in combination with the plural "samples", or is it more correct to write **levels**?

> The **levels** of residual host cell protein in all drug **samples** comply with the regulatory requirements.

Might not this singular "level" in sentence 1 be understood (incorrectly) to mean "in some samples it goes beyond the prescribed limits, but the mean level meets the requirements"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are probably using "all" to mean "each individually"

> The **levels** of residual host cell protein in **all** drug samples comply...

the alternative would be

> The **level** of residual host cell protein in **each drug sample complies**...

Answer (score 3):

The second sentence makes more sense because the samples have slightly different (but still compliant) proportions of residual host cell protein. This feels "natural" because one expects biological samples to differ slightly from each other, as opposed to samples from an engineered product.

If the intention was to aggregate the results of the sample set under a single value (assuming that it is statistically valid to do so -- large variances make this questionable), then it would be acceptable to use the first sentence.